# Enum: consistency of “illegal forward references”

Tags: java, constructor, enums, arguments

When calling an enum constructor with a constant of the same class, the compiler requires its qualified name, as in the following sample:

```
enum Animal
{
    CAT     (MAMMAL),           // this notation doesn't compile
    LIZARD  (Animal.REPTILE),   // this one does
    DOG     (Animal.MAMMAL);

    private static final int MAMMAL  = 0;
    private static final int REPTILE = 1;

    private int family;

    Animal(int family)
    {
        this.family = family;
    }
}
```

Failing to comply results in an `illegal forward reference`: the compiler thinks of `MAMMAL` as an instance of this enum yet undeclared at this point (like `DOG`) instead of as a constant; this is ridiculous given that no constructor accepts a parameter of type `Animal`.

Why does the compiler take the pain to check whether `MAMMAL` is a constant or an instance of `Animal` only when using the syntax `Animal.MAMMAL`?

Answer (score 0):

May be a bug in java compiler as describe here [forward reference](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6676362)